# AES CBC Encryption Key & Special ASCII characters

Tags: encryption, aes, sha-256, encoding, hash-signature

Can we add characters like `α` `π` `Σ` `µ` `σ` `♂`   `╩` `Φ` `¥` `∩` `∞` `ε` in the AES 256bit CBC Encryption Key?

Does it make the key more unique?

In my VB.NET application I am using a key like this: "`∩TY&Hjubf78▐Φ4≥╬V% ÷⌡Uαπ^f7cHJßF`"

Does it make any difference in Encrypting the data?

Comment: How much this differs from your previous question and the answer? [Special characters in AES Encryption Key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89668/18298)